# A riddle set in White Plume Mountain

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I'm going to run the D&D adventure White Plume Mountain, and I want to replace one of the puzzles with a good riddle.

Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

Comment: is a [tag:knowledge] tag needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The mage with the mansion:

   > Mordenkainen
   >
   >  There is a D&D spell "Mordenkainen's magnificent mansion"
2. The sorcerer who did surgery:

   > Strange (Found by Alexander Geldhof)
   >
   >  Dr. Strange, doctor = surgery
3. The bro with the fist bumps

   > Bigby
   >
   >  There are several fist-related D&D spells such as "Bigby's clenched fist" and "Bigby's crushing hand"
4. The guide who was the gray

   > Gandalf
   >
   >  Gandalf the gray, who guided Bilbo and Frodo
5. The one with the orbs

   > Otiluke
   >
   >  There are several D&D spells that are orb-related such as "Otiluke's Freezing Sphere" and "Otiluke's Resilient Sphere"
6. The villain who talked to vipers

   > Voldemort (found by Alexander Geldhof)
   >
   >  From Harry Potter, who famously could talk to snakes
7. The channeler with the conflagration

   > Chandra
   >
   >  From Magic the Gathering, where there are several fire-related cards, such as "Chandra, Pyromancer" and "Chandra, Acolyte of Flame"
8. The enchantress who was endothermic

   > Elsa
   >
   >  From Frozen the movie, who had ice powers
9. And the greatest wizard of them all

   > Keraptis
   >
   >  From D&D's White Plume Mountain adventure module, where this riddle is set (from the title).

Solution:

> If you take the letters in the numbered blanks 1..11 from the previous answers, and fill in the given blanks _____ ______, you get:
>
>  **FINAL ANSWER**

Solution #2:

> If you take the original version with the scrabble tiles, and remove the names of the 9 wizards, you get these letters:
>
>  EILST
>
>  Which anagrams to **TILES**.

Comment: So which one is the actual answer to the riddle?

Comment: The first one is the actual answer. The second is an answer to a previous version of the riddle.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe this is obvious, but my guess at the method of the puzzle is that we are supposed to decypher the cryptic clues and then scrap them from the letters. I suppose 'The villain who talked to vipers' is Voldemort, 'the sorceror who did surgery' is (Dr./Doctor) Strange. Note that those both alliterate with the cryptic clues they correspond to.

Comment: Correct so far! Some of these will require D&D knowledge.

Comment: I decided the Scrabble tiles thing was too difficult, so I replaced it with an indexing thing.  There's some redundancy, so now I think the puzzle should be much easier.